# Кроссплатформенные тесты .NET Core

Tags: linux, windows, юнит-тесты, .net-core

Всем доброго времени суток!

У меня есть необходимость тестировать определенные функции, которые работаю с файлами на ПК. Заключается вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы путь понимался как Windows, так и Linux? Насколько мне известно, в Windows путь прописывается `some\folder`, а в Linux `some/folder`

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать относительный путь, необходимо воспользоваться функцией `Path.Combine`.